# PowerShell rename refactor (F2) does nothing in VS Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, refactoring

Pressing F2 when editing a PowerShell file does nothing in VS Code.
(for other languages like C#, Python rename refactor (F2) works fine)

**What I've tried:**

- completely uninstalled MS PowerShell extension and reinstalled it, including VS Code restarts
- checked the Keyboard Shortcuts: PowerShell keybindings are present when PowerShell extension is installed, not present when uninstalled
- Rename Symbol (editor.action.rename) is bind to F2 (and again, it works for other languages)
- Edited file extension is .PS1, I can run and debug it, so VS Code recognizes (?) it a PowerShell file

Comment: rename refactor is not supported for powershell unfortunately. it would be very difficult to make it work robustly which such a dynamic language. also see: https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1440

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently supported by [VS Code's builtin PowerShell language support](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/powershell) or the non-builtin [PowerShell VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), but there is an open feature-request issue ticket for it: [F2 (rename) doesn't work for PowerShell variables #1440](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1440), and also ["Smart" variable rename
#261](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/261). I suggest that you give those issue tickets a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to them to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump". If you're interested in helping implement the feature, there's [related guidance here](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1440#issuecomment-476890853).

Answer (score 1):

To add to [starball's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77515268/45375):

Indeed, the PowerShell extension does *not* offer renaming refactoring as of this writing, and it is important to note that **given PowerShell's *dynamic* - rather than *lexical* - scoping, renaming [cannot be implemented *robustly*](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/261#issuecomment-465249755).**<sup>[1]</sup>

This is the primary reason this feature hasn't materialized after years of debate: **any implementation would amount to a *compromise* that makes certain assumptions and *can break code***. Striking the right balance between utility and safety is a tricky proposition, and there's also the aspect of needing to *inform the user* of the potential of breaking code.

That said, you can **roll your own implementation**, building on the great proof-of-concept provided by [Patrick Meineke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930135/patrick-meinecke) [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/261#issuecomment-1366886686), which allows you to choose which tradeoffs to make.

Here's a **sample implementation** based on the proof-of-concept that has the following **limitations** and makes the following **choices**:

- Limitations:

  - Only renaming *variables* is supported (not also functions, methods, ...) ...
  - ... in the *same file*.
  - For technical reasons, the rename operation *isn't atomic*, which means that *each* document modification made in the course of renaming is a *separate operation* in terms of undo / redo functionality. To undo a renaming, it is therefore simpler to rename *again* and specify the old name.
  - Due to an apparent bug, invoking the renaming from inside a `param(...)` block, to rename a specific *parameter* variable, doesn't work as of the PSES (PowerShell Editor Services) version that comes with v2023.8.0 of the PowerShell extension - see [GitHub issue #2120](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellEditorServices/issues/2120). However, it does work if you place the cursor inside or next to a later *reference* to such a variable.
- Choices made:

  - Only variables with the *same (non-)prefix* are renamed (see exception re `$using:` below); e.g., invoking the function on `$script:foo` only renames reference to `$script:foo`, not also `$foo`
  - A `$using:` reference (in remoting / job / `ForEach-Object -Parallel` contexts) is treated like a non-prefixed variable, so that renaming `$foo` also renames `$using:foo` and vice versa.
  - *Caveat*: The above implies that if you happen to use a *local* variable in a remoting / job / `ForEach-Object -Parallel` context that happens to have the same name as non-prefixed variable in the caller's scope, it is renamed too.
  - Whenever renaming is performed, a preexisting `{...}` enclosure of the name (e.g, `${foo}`) is *retained*; otherwise, such an enclosure is only applied if *necessary* due to special characters in the new name.

**To use the implementation below**:

- Make sure that profile loading is enabled for the PowerShell extension:

  - Open the user settings (<kbd>Ctrl-,</kbd>), search for `powershell profile`, and make sure that `PowerShell: Enable Profile Loading` is checked.
- Then, with a PowerShell file being displayed in the active editor, i.e. with the PIC (PowerShell-Integrated Console) running in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal, open the extension-specific profile file for editing by running `psedit $PROFILE` and paste the code below.
- Then, in order to bind the <kbd>F2</kbd> key to the custom function, open your `keybindings.json` file (via the command palette (<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-P</kbd>): `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`) and add the following:

  ```bash
  {
    "key": "F2",
    "command": "PowerShell.InvokeRegisteredEditorCommand",
    "args": {
      "commandName": "Rename-Variable"
    },
    "when": "editorLangId == 'powershell' && editorTextFocus"
  }
  ```

**Code to paste into `$PROFILE`**:

```bash
function Rename-Variable {
  param($Context)

  # Get the AST element at the cursor position.
  $variable = Find-Ast -AtCursor
  if ($variable -isnot [System.Management.Automation.Language.VariableExpressionAst]) {
    $psEditor.Window.ShowWarningMessage('No variable found at current cursor location.')
    return
  }

  # Prompt for a new name.
  $esp = [Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Extensions.EditorObjectExtensions, Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices]::GetExtensionServiceProvider($psEditor)
  $newName = $esp.EditorUI.PromptInputAsync('Enter new variable name').GetAwaiter().GetResult().Trim()

  # Validate the name; enclose in {...}, if necessary.
  if (-not $newName) { return }
  $isSpecialName = $newName -match '[^\p{L}\p{Nd}_]'
  if ($isSpecialName -and $newName -match '[}{]') { $newName = $newName -replace '[}{]', '`$&' }

  # Rename all references to variables with the *same name and prefix* in the 
  # current document.
  Find-Ast { $_.VariablePath.UserPath -eq $variable.VariablePath.UserPath } |
    Sort-Object { $_.Extent.StartOffset } -Descending |
    ForEach-Object {
      $usingPrefix = if ($_.Extent -match '^\$\{?using:') { 'using:' }
      $prefix = if ($_.VariablePath -match ':') { $_.VariablePath -replace  '(?<=:).+$' }      
      $openDelim = if ($isSpecialName -or $_.Extent -like '${*') { '{' }
      $closeDelim = if ($openDelim) { '}' }
      $sigil = if ($_.Splatted) { '@' } else { '$' }
      $Context.CurrentFile.InsertText(
        ($sigil + $openDelim + $usingPrefix + $prefix + $newName + $closeDelim),
        $_.Extent.StartLineNumber,
        $_.Extent.StartColumnNumber,
        $_.Extent.EndLineNumber,
        $_.Extent.EndColumnNumber)
    }    
}

Register-EditorCommand -Name Rename-Variable -ScriptBlock ${function:Rename-Variable} -DisplayName 'Rename variables in the current document'
```

---

<sup>[1] This challenge is also the reason that the only refactoring functionality offered (via <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-R</kbd>) is simple `Surround With:` functionality around the currently selected text.</sup>

Comment: Many thx for your detailed thoughts. I am not a language expert, so the question raises in my mind, how Python rename refactor is with us without any serious trouble?

Comment: @g.pickardou, presumably because Python uses _lexical_ rather than dynamic scoping, which can be reasoned about _statically, at design time_, whereas the behavior of PowerShell's (highly unfortunate) _dynamic_ scoping isn't known until _runtime_.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+F2` allows you to "Change All Occurrences" of a function name or variable.